# Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.SOMETHING)

Tags: c#, .net

I've been trying out the most of the `Enviroment.SpecialFolder` enumeration, but I think there isn't any way of what I'd like to accomplish with the enumeration *only*. Using the `string.Substring()` method brought me the farest, yet.

I try to get just the system partition path, where windows is actually installed. On machine A it might be `C:\`, on machine B it might be `D:\`.

The most sufficent solution, I found so far was

```
var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows)
                      .Substring(0, 3);
```

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: That seems pretty optimal to me.  What are you trying to improve?

Comment: I was just wondering that there isn't any member of this enumeration, which actually returns exactly what I'd like. A lot of stuff is covered by it, so I just feared, that I've overseen something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the drive, use `Path.GetPathRoot`.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getpathroot.aspx

```
var root = Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need "disk where Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows" your sample is ok.

You may want to use [Path.GetPathRoot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getpathroot%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead of Susbstring...

Note that you probably should not write anything to the root drive yourself (if your program is designed to behave nice).